# Visual Studio 2015 toolbox not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, toolbox

I want to use items from the toolbox, but my Visual Studio environment looks like this:

[image: Visual Studio Toolbox Problem]

I tried to fix it and I did what is advised in [this MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f8b98421-5d68-4bfa-ab02-5a23b13338fc/visual-studio-2015-toolbox-missing?forum=vssetup), but it didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Fixed link to image and inlined the link to MSDN post.